# Multivariate adaptive regression splines(MARS) Analysis

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I am working on mars analysis where my DV is ordinal data. I know, we can easily upload the data set in SPM in which MARS is trademarked and licensed. but i am running the analysis in R, where i need to prepare the train and test data set. This is where i am getting stuck.

I am not sure, how to validate my train model with test data set in MARS as we can do other linear and logistic regression models. How do we validate MARS model and what are the measures we use?